# Creating an Orchard query sort criteria with an agregate function

Tags: orchardcms

I'm making a ISortCriterionProvider in Orchard so I can sort items by the number of tags that match a given list of tags.

This is my sort criterion function so far:

```
public void ApplySortCriterion(SortCriterionContext context)
{
    IEnumberable<int> tagIdsToFilterOn = GetTagIds();

    Action<IAliasFactory> selector =
        alias => alias.ContentPartRecord<TagsPartRecord>()
            .Property("Tags", "tags").Property("TagRecord", "tagRecord");

    // Todo: Somehow add return value from GetTagMatchCount()
    //       into a TagMatchCount property in selector

    Action<IHqlSortFactory> filter = x => x.Asc("TagMatchCount");

    // apply sort
    context.Query = context.Query.OrderBy(selector, filter);
}

public int GetTagMatchCount(IEnumerable<TagRecord> tags,
                            IEnumerable<int> tagIds)
{
    tags.Count(t => tagIds.Contains(t.Id));
}
```

The filter for the query needs a named property. I want to calculate a property using GetTagMatchCount(tagsOnCurrentItem, tagIdsToFilterOn) and order based on that.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: did you figure this one out in the end?

Comment: No, I'm not sure you can at the moment.